# No output in speech recognition module of python

Tags: python-3.x, ubuntu, alsa

When i run below python script it shows some error.

```
import speech_recognition as s    

sr=s.Recognizer()
print("Please, speak now....")
with s.Microphone() as m:
  audio=sr.listen(m)
  query=sr.recognize_google(audio,language='eng-in')
  print(query)
```

I tried almost all solution available online but still my problem is not solved.
The error massage in command line is:

```
ALSA lib pcm_dmix.c:1089:(snd_pcm_dmix_open) unable to open slave
ALSA lib pcm.c:2642:(snd_pcm_open_noupdate) Unknown PCM cards.pcm.rear
ALSA lib pcm.c:2642:(snd_pcm_open_noupdate) Unknown PCM cards.pcm.center_lfe
ALSA lib pcm.c:2642:(snd_pcm_open_noupdate) Unknown PCM cards.pcm.side
ALSA lib pcm_route.c:869:(find_matching_chmap) Found no matching channel map
connect(2) call to /dev/shm/jack-1000/default/jack_0 failed (err=No such file or directory)
attempt to connect to server failed
connect(2) call to /dev/shm/jack-1000/default/jack_0 failed (err=No such file or directory)
attempt to connect to server failed
ALSA lib pcm_oss.c:377:(_snd_pcm_oss_open) Unknown field port
ALSA lib pcm_oss.c:377:(_snd_pcm_oss_open) Unknown field port
ALSA lib pcm_usb_stream.c:486:(_snd_pcm_usb_stream_open) Invalid type for card
ALSA lib pcm_usb_stream.c:486:(_snd_pcm_usb_stream_open) Invalid type for card
ALSA lib pcm_dmix.c:1089:(snd_pcm_dmix_open) unable to open slave
connect(2) call to /dev/shm/jack-1000/default/jack_0 failed (err=No such file or directory)
attempt to connect to server failed
```

But when i run this python script on jupyter-notebook or Pycharm it does't show any error but still not taking any input from microphone(but microphone start) and also not showing any output.

Comment: Are you able to use the microphone on your computer for e.g. skype, sound recording? It looks like a hardware/driver issue.

Comment: Yes my microphone is working properly.

Comment: Crosscheck by using arecord filename.wav .